# How to stop redirect on-click wishlist icon

Tags: magento2.4, wishlist

My wishlist code:

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

/** @var Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Wishlist $block */
?>
<?php if ($block->getWishlistHelper()->isAllow()) : ?>


<a href="#"
class="action towishlist"
title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Wish List')) ?>"
aria-label="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Wish List')) ?>"
data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAddToWishlistParams($block->getProduct()) ?>'
data-action="add-to-wishlist"
role="button">
<img class="whislist-icon product-id-<?php echo $block->getProduct()->getId();?>" src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/whislist_icon.jpg'); ?>" />
<span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')) ?></span>
</a>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();
$mediaUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$wishimage = $mediaUrl."after_added.jpg";
?>

<script>
require(['jquery'], function($){
jQuery.ajax({
url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('addtowish/index/wishlist') ?>',
method: 'get',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
var wislistAddesCheckData = data;
var itemLenth = wislistAddesCheckData.items.length;
for(i=0;i<itemLenth; i++){
var wislistAddedProductId = wislistAddesCheckData.items[i].product_id;
$(".product-id-"+wislistAddedProductId).attr('src','<?php echo $wishimage ; ?>');
}
}
});
});
</script>
```

Now, if click wishlist icon its redirect to the wishlist landing page, how to stop that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change code as per i have added here. Also modified it as per your need.

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

/** @var Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Wishlist $block */
?>
<?php if ($block->isWishListAllowed()) : ?>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="action" id="custom-wishlist"
        title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Wish List')) ?>"
        aria-label="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Wish List')) ?>" role="button">
        <img class="whislist-icon product-id-<?php echo $block->getProduct()->getId();?>" src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/whislist_icon.jpg'); ?>" />
        <?php
            $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $storeManager = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
            $currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();
            $mediaUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
            $wishimage = $mediaUrl."after_added.jpg";
        ?>
        <img class="whislist-icon show-img-<?php echo $block->getProduct()->getId();?>" src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $wishimage; ?>" style="display:none;"/>
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')) ?></span>
    </a>

    <script>
    require(['jquery','Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function($,customerData){
        $( "#custom-wishlist" ).click(function() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('hideorders/index/wishlist') ?>',
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    productId: "<?php echo $block->getProduct()->getId() ?>"
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data.productid);
                    var productId = data.productid;
                    $(".product-id-"+productId).hide();
                    $(".show-img-"+productId).show();
                    //Do whatever you want to do
                    var sections = ['wishlist'];
                    customerData.invalidate(sections);
                    customerData.reload(sections, true);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

> Please create controller file Wishlist.php file

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Zmagecommerce. All rights reserved.
 */
namespace PackageName\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

class wishlist extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action 
{
    protected $_customerSession;

    protected $_resultJsonFactory;

    protected $wishlistProvider;

    protected $_wishlistRepository;

    protected $_productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistRepository,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface $wishlistProvider,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_wishlistRepository= $wishlistRepository;
        $this->_resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->wishlistProvider = $wishlistProvider;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $response = [];
        $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('productId');
        $customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
        if($productId && $customerId) {
            try {
                $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                $product = null;
            }

            if($product) {
                $wishlist = $this->_wishlistRepository->create()->loadByCustomerId($customerId, true);
                $wishlist->addNewItem($product);
                $wishlist->save();
                $response['productid'] = $productId; 
            }
        }

        $resultJson = $this->_resultJsonFactory->create();
        $resultJson->setData($response);
        return $resultJson;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to update the wishlist icon after product added to the wishlist, can you pls help me with this also, thanks.

Comment: Yes , i will update my code in few mins.

Comment: I have updated my answer in above both the file according to your need. Please check and let me know on this.

Comment: Could you please approve and upvote this?

Comment: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Wishlist\Interceptor::isWishListAllowed, any help thanks

Comment: For your magento please use $block->getWishlistHelper()->isAllow().

Comment: Which magento version you are using? I have added code which is implemented in version magento 2.3.6

Comment: Magento 2.4.1 commerce edition.

Comment: is this $block->getWishlistHelper()->isAllow() working for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120032/discussion-between-zealousweb-and-zus).

Comment: ANy help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/333645/57334

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code. And you need to modify your code like below.

Because of "data-post" , it redirects.

```
data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAddToWishlistParams($block->getProduct()) ?>'  , this is passing data like below


{"action":"http:\/\/localhost\/magento2\/demo\/magento236\/wishlist\/index\/add\/","data":{"product":1,"uenc":"aHR0cDovL3NpdGVwcm9vZnMubmV0L21hZ2VudG8yL2Rod2FuaS9tYWdlbnRvMjM2L3Rlc3QtcHJvZHVjdC5odG1sP3F0eT00"}}
```

That's why it is redirects from above action. You have to remove "data-post" from your add to wishlist link and you have to pass data in your ajax call. Also you have to pass product id and other needed data in ajax call.

After that in your controller file , you have to load prodcut object by product id and add product in wishlist programmatically.

Comment: Thank you, and how to implement ajax for wishlist icon, i need if click wishlist icon the product added wishlist without refresh the page.

Comment: I will post my answer in few mins for you