# Magento 2 - How to remove products from Wishlist if click again same Wishlist icon?

Tags: magento2.4.1

How to remove the products from wishlist if again click the wishlist icon?

How to implement on my wishlist icon -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/166263/57334

Comment: You need to override the proper phtml file and implement the code there.

Comment: Can you pls explain in detail pls, i need if customer click again wishlist icon which is the products already available in wishlist  should be removed. I am already add Magento_Wishlist in  : app\design\frontend\Zero\My-theme\Magento_Wishlist

Comment: I can't able to find any relevant information.

Comment: I post the answer please check that one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following steps.

1. Identify the tag (span, p etc) which show the Whishlist Icon to the customer.
2. On that tag, put onclick Ajax request.
3. On Ajax request pass the required parameter to controller actions.
4. Now do the coding into the controller according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use this free plugin for ajax wishlist.
https://marketplace.magento.com/codesicle-module-wishlist-ajax.html